# How is it possible to print the item at index -8 when there are only 4 items in the tuple?

Tags: python

I'm learning python, I just don't know how does this code works cause it has only 4 items.

```
val=("indore", "pune", "Goa", "Delhi")
print(val[-8:-3])
```

I wrote the codes in Pycharm and the output was this: `('indore',)`

I was expecting an error

Answer (score 2):

Even you give `out of range` integer indexes like:

```
print(val[-58:-32])
print(val[200:300])
print(val[-1134:-32435])
```

These will **not** throw any error and shows empty tuple since items in these indexes are not available. So, you should not expect any error while doing slicing in list or tuples.

See here:

```
Items -> "indore", "pune", "Goa", "Delhi"
Index ->   -4        -3      -2     -1
```

In your answer, it is only showing 'indore' because items from index -8 to -5 is not available, so it is showing the item of -4 index which is 'indore'.

**Note** that it wont show item of index -3 ('pune') as it is upper limit.

Answer (score -1):

> Slicing tuples
>
> Tuple slicing is a frequent practice in Python, and it is the most
> prevalent technique used by programmers to solve efficient problems.
> Consider a Python tuple. You must slice a tuple in order to access a
> range of elements in it. One method is to utilize the colon as a
> simple slicing operator (:).
>
> The slice operator allows you to specify where to begin slicing, where
> to stop slicing, and what step to take. **Tuple slicing creates a new
> tuple from an old one.**

source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-index-and-slice-a-tuple-in-Python

**You don't get an error because slicing creates a new tuple.**

```
val=("indore", "pune", "Goa", "Delhi")
index   -4       -3      -2      -1
```

Your `val[-8:-3]` tries to find values from -8 index to -4.

Indexes -8, -7, -6, and -5 doesn't exist. -4 Exists and returns the value "indore".

So a new tuple is returned with one value the value "indore".
If you try `val[-8:-4]`an empty tuple will be returned.

Comment: Slicing creates a new tuple, but that fact alone doesn't actually explain what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @user2357112. I have edit the question to be more specific. @user23111381 mentioned that `I was expecting an error` so i focused on that to answer the question.